# How to connect to a specific Wi-fi automatically using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, wifi

I would like that once I press a button, the Flutter app will connect to a specific Wi-Fi access point (specifically, it will connect to an ESP8266). However, I wouldn't like the user to have to manually select the network. I want it to be done automatically when they click a button in the app, and once a certain amount of time has passed, it should disconnect automatically as well.

Is it possible to be done in Flutter or would it be necessary to go to Kotlin or Java?

I researched some Flutter libraries but they do not seem to have this funcitonality

Comment: Here's an answer from couple of year ago, don't know if it may be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904640/ask-user-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ask user to connect to a specific WiFi flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904640/ask-user-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-flutter)